# Cotangent lift of the embedding is zero

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, robotics

I am reading the work on variatonal collision integrators from the programmers point of view, since I want to implement it is the software. The work is publicly available here: [caltech](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/records/19pap-vc965). I want to implement elastic collision, but I don't understand one equation, for instance, number 13:

$$
i^*\big(D_4L_d(\overline{q}_i, \tilde{\overline{q}}) + D_2L_d(\tilde{\overline{q}}, \overline{q}_{i+1})\big) = 0
$$

Where

> $i^*: T^*Q \rightarrow T^*\partial C$ is the cotangent lift of the embedding $i: \partial C \rightarrow Q$.

While I have a general understanding that $i$ stands for inclusion map, since $\partial C$ is the boundary of $C \subset Q$, I completely don't understand what is cotangent lift and what it means in terms of equation.

I would be glad if someone can explain me what does it mean and, more importantly, what I can read to interpret these notations much easier without deep diving in related courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have a smooth map $f:M\to N$ between two manifolds, the cotangent lift $f^*:\Omega^1(N)\to \Omega^1(M)$ is a mapping from 1-forms on $N$ to 1-forms on $M$ given by
$$
(f^*\alpha)_m := \alpha_{f(m)}\circ T_mf
$$
where $\alpha\in\Omega^1(N)$ is a 1-form on $N$, $m\in M$, and $T_mf:T_mM\to T_{f(m)}N$ is the derivative map of $f$ at $m$.

In your case where $i:\partial C \to Q$, the derivative map $T_ci$ is quite simple (it's just the "obvious" inclusion of $T_c\partial C$ into $T_{i(c)}Q$, where we're identifying $\partial C$ and $i(\partial C)\subset Q$), and so for $\alpha\in \Omega^1(Q)$ and $c\in\partial C$,
$$
(i^*\alpha)_c = \alpha_{i(c)}\circ T_ci = \alpha_{i(c)}\vert_{T_c\partial C}.
$$
That is, $(i^*\alpha)_c$ is obtained by taking the element $\alpha_{i(c)}\in T^*_{i(c)}Q$ at $i(c)$, and restricting it to $T_c\partial C$ (the tangent space to $\partial C$ at $c$).

In short, equation 13 is saying that the 1-form in brackets vanishes when applied to vectors that are tangent to the boundary $\partial C$.

Probably the best place to learn this notation is ["Mechanics and Symmetry - Second Edition" by Marsden and Ratiu](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-21792-5). Specifically Section 4.2 for the general notion of pullback of a differential form, and Section 6.3 for the notion of cotangent lift.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Definitely going to check the reference. However, I have the question, I thought that this equation means we can move only in direction normal to the surface, since we “bounce” back on collision. However moving tangent does not make sense for me. I suggest that for ball bouncing on the table, configuration set is x,y,z, while boundary of admissible configurations is x,y,0, with the table at z=0 as the surface we bounce from

Comment: I haven't read the paper, so I don't know the full context. But right afterwards it says this is a discrete version of equation (8), and that equation "implies conservation of  momentum tangent to the contact surface". So it does not seem correct to me that motion can only be normal to the surface. Note, the notion of normality would require a metric on the space $Q$, and I don't see one mentioned anywhere.